# Add a character to the text on mobile version using CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a text block on my website:

> ### Specialtyreagents

```
<h1>Specialtyreagents</h1>
```

Can I somehow add a `-` symbol to this block within CSS, so it should looks like this:

> ### Specialty-reagents

I can use only CSS in my case!

Thank you for your help.

Comment: simply put, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pseudoelement with the word you want on mobile, and use font-size to hide or show it.

**example**

[codepen](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/OpWVBq)

```css
h1:after {
  content: 'Specialty-reagents';
  font-size: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  h1:after {
    font-size: 32px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Specialtyreagents</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

With just CSS you can't include that `-` but if you need to use it in a specific case you can write again the text like this with a pseudo-element:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 0;
}
h1:before {
  content: "Specialty-reagents";
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<h2>Specialtyreagents</h2>
<h1>Specialtyreagents</h1>
```

Comment: That will display the text with a hyphen on desktop and mobile. OP wanted hyphen only on mobile.

Comment: As far my interpretation the main problem here is how to add the `-`so I focus on that but anyway there is the asnwer from ovokuro your post is just the copy of these two by the way @DanielJames

Answer (score 1):

On the long ride you can have two html elements, one for mobile and one for desktop:

```
<h1 class="desktop">Specialtyreagents</h1>
```

and

```
<h1 class="mobile" >Specialty-reagents</h1>
```

Then, you should have some css code for handling it:

```
.desktop {
    display: block;
}
.mobile {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
    .desktop {
        display: none;
    }
    .mobile {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP can only alter CSS

Answer (score 1):

With media query:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  h1 > span:after {
    content: "-";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Specialty<span></span>reagents</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you can use a pseudo element to achieve this.

The best way to go is to just add a new pseudo element when viewing on a small viewport (ie. a mobile phone). Here is some extra [info on pseudo elements](https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/) and how they can be used.

*Example...*

```css
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    
        h1 {
            font-size: 0px;
        }
    
        h1::after {
            font-size: 30px;
            display: block;
            content: "Specialty-reagents";
        }
    
    }
```

```html
<h1>Specialtyreagents</h1>
```

The only thing you may need to change if the `max-width` for the media query and the `font size` of the heading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for the solution please:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  h1 > span:after {
    content: "-";
  }
}
```